# Python - match closest values from 2 tables in excel

Tags: python, excel

I have two tables, one with wind speed data and the other with CO2 data.  Each has unix time stamps, but all the times don't match up perfectly.  I would like to pair the data according to the closest possible times.  Is there a way to achieve this using python logic and/or pandas?

Example:

```
Time      CO2                   Time         Wind
13982034  300                   13984094     3.4
13985000  303                   14034957     4.5
14029480  301
```

And the desired result would be:

```
Time      CO2   Wind       
13982034  300   3.4               
13985000  303   3.4               
14029480  301   4.5
```

Comment: Just to clarify; are you always trying to match wind measurements to each CO2 measurement - i.e. there are more CO2 than wind measurements? Also what have you tried so far - people will be able to help you far better if they see what code you've tried and where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's basic sorting and searching (Knuth, vol 2).  :-)

This transcends any particular implementation language or package.

1. Sort your look-up list (the wind speeds)
2. Iterate through your CO2 list.

For each CO2 entry ...

- Search by time stamp for the place that time would be inserted into the list.  If it's a long list (say > 100 rows), use a binary or interpolation search.
- This gives you two neighboring entries.  A simple `if` statement will indicate the nearer one.
- Steal the wind speed from that entry, and add it to the record in the CO2 table.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate wind times and for each value find the CO2 time with the smallest difference.

```
co2_times = [13982034, 13985000, 14029480]
wind_times = [13984094, 14034957]

for wt in wind_times:
     closestTime = min(co2_times, key=lambda c:abs(c-wt))
     print("Wind Time: " + str(wt) + "\nClosest CO2 Time: " + str(closestTime) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
Wind Time: 13984094
Closest CO2 Time: 13985000

Wind Time: 14034957
Closest CO2 Time: 14029480
```

Note that if run time is important you should look at the answer provided by @Prune. Sorting and binary search will give you much better performance, but if your lists aren't that large than run times will be negligible.